# How can I make a trigger that updates a column when another table has been completed?

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

-topic-

I have a table called ORDERLINE which has multiple columns.

another table called ORDERHEADER has a column called Order_completed which will be set to the system date when all the orders columns have been fulfilled.

How can I do this using triggers?

The way I would try it is

```
    CREATE TRIGGER orderhascompleted
    AFTER (all values in ORDERLINE has been completed)
    BEGIN
    INSERT INTO ORDERHEADER (Order_completed) VALUES (NOW())
```

How can I do this? In C++ I would use a simple if statement, but I don't think that is possible in SQL

Comment: How do you know when "all the orders columns have been fulfilled"

Comment: when all the columns are not null because they have had data added

Comment: Can the orderline table be updated subsequent to that? What if there are multiple orderline rows for an orderheader row?

Comment: this is not something you should do with a trigger. there are really very few things that you should do with a trigger.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using the :NEW.[FIELD] using a IF statement in a trigger declare like this :

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER [NAME] AFTER UPDATE
    ON [TABLE]
    FOR EACH ROW
    REFERENCING OLD AS OLD NEW AS NEW
```

Would do the job.

The If statement can look like this

```
If (:OLD.FIELD IS NOT NULL OR :NEW.FIELD IS NOT NULL) AND ... THEN
  UPDATE [TABLE]...
END IF;
```